# Error while accessing bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have defined one bean in beans.xml:

```
 <bean id="ABCManagerImpl"
      class="com.xyz.manager.impl.ABCManagerImpl" scope="singleton">
       <property name="abcDAO" ref="ABCDAO" />
       <property name="accountManager" ref="AccountManager"/>     
</bean>
```

And in following JAVA file I am accessing this bean like following:

```
  public class BankFactory implements ApplicationContextAware{

      private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

      @Override
      public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
          this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
      }
      public ABCManager getManager(String bankName){
           ABCManager abcManager = null;
           abcManager =      
               applicationContext.getBean(ABCManagerImpl.class);
     }
}
```

But in the above line applicationContext.getBean(ABCManagerImpl.class), I am getting following error:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xyz.manager.impl.ABCManagerImpl] is defined.
```

Comment: is your class `ABCManagerImpl` behind proxy (transactional)?

Comment: No it is not behind proxy(transactional).

Comment: How you initialize your `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: Does your class `ABCManagerImpl` implement an Interface (e.g. `ABCManager`)? In this case, try `applicationContext.getBean(ABCManager.class)` to obtain the bean.

Comment: Could you also write the code for implementation of `ABCManagerImpl` class for better understanding ?

Comment: @andolsizied It implements ApplicationContextAware, so no separate initialization of application context is required, I think.

Comment: try to load bean by interface type : `applicationContext.getBean(ABCManager.class)`